# How to set the website to preloadEnabled on Windows/IIS 8.5 platform in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, iis, asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a small .NET Core app deployed to Elastic Beanstalk under Windows/IIS platform.  The app works great.  However, I would like to set it to preload so that it goes through initialization without someone having to hit the website.

Typically this is accomplished by `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set app "Default Web Site/" /preloadenabled:true`, among others.  So I've created a command in my `.ebextensions` folder:

File: 04_preload_enabled.config

```
commands:
 set_preload_enabled:
  command: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set app "Default Web Site/" /preloadenabled:true
```

There are 3 other files that run before this one to setup the application pool (see below).  However, upon deployment, the website's preloadEnabled setting still remains at `false`.  If I terminal into the Elastic Beanstalk instance and run these commands at the command prompt, everything is setup properly.

What am I missing and how do I set preloadEnabled to true?

P.S.  Ebextension commands that run before the 04_preload_enabled.config

File: 01_idle_time.config

```
commands:
 set_idle_time:
  command: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:applicationPools "/[name='DefaultAppPool'].processModel.idleTimeout:0.00:00:00"
```

File: 02_auto_start.config

```
commands:
 set_auto_start:
  command: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:applicationPools "/[name='DefaultAppPool'].autoStart:true"
```

File: 03_start_mode.config

```
commands:
 set_start_mode:
  command: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:applicationPools "/[name='DefaultAppPool'].startMode:AlwaysRunning"
```